# tabindex="-1" on <ul> doesn't work

Tags: html, tabindex

I have a mega dropdown menu like this from bootstrap (code simplified) :

```
<li class="dropdown mega-dropdown">
   <a href="#">Menu Button</a>
   <ul tabindex="-1">
      <li>1st Link</li>
      <li>2nd Link</li>
      <!-- many other links -->
   </ul>
   <!-- many other menu buttons -->
</li>
```

Small fiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/48m2ppzc/

I want to simplify the navigation with the tab key :

- At the beginning the element `<ul>` has a `max-height`of  `0px` so I shoudn't be able to navigate inside it with the tab key (because the menu is hidden).
- When I click on the "Menu Button" link, the menu should show up (I set `max-height` to  `500px`), and I need to change the tabindex to '0' (I can do it with JQuery so that's not a problem)

The problem is at the first point : `tabindex="-1"` doesn't work, I can still navigate inside the menu with the tab key.

How can I fix this problem? I use HTML5 so `tabindex` should work on all HTML elements, I also tried with `tabindex="0"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tabindex` is not inherited by the children of an element, so you need to set it manually on all items:

```
<li class="dropdown mega-dropdown">
   <a href="#">Menu Button</a>
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">1st Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">2nd Link</a></li>
      <!-- many other links -->
   </ul>
   <!-- many other menu buttons -->
</li>
```

Since this is probably accessibility related, it might help semantically to use the [`aria-hidden`](https://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2012/05/html5-accessibility-chops-hidden-and-aria-hidden/) attribute as well (and toggle it, once it is visible):

```
<li class="dropdown mega-dropdown">
   <a href="#">Menu Button</a>
   <ul aria-hidden="true">
      <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">1st Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">2nd Link</a></li>
      <!-- many other links -->
   </ul>
   <!-- many other menu buttons -->
</li>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @nils, have a nice day!

Comment: Thanks, same to you :)